# powershell foreach-object parallel - Not all properties of piped in object are available

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Consider below code

```
$users = get-aduser -filter $filter -properties samAccountName,lastLogonTimestamp
$users|foreach -parallel {
   [do something with $_.samAccountName]   # --> this works fine. samAccountName can be read properly
   [do something with $_.lastLogonTimestamp]    # --> this doesn't work. lastLogonTimestamp is always NULL regardless if it is actually populated

}
```

Same issue reading whenChanged, whenCreated. What do I miss here?

NOTE: This question is not about referencing an external variable. It's about property visibility of THE piped in object, which is supposed to be fully accessible in the script block.

Same code in non-parallel flavor works fine

```
$users = get-aduser -filter $filter -properties samAccountName,lastLogonTimestamp
$users|foreach {
   [do something with $_.samAccountName]   # --> this works fine. samAccountName can be read properly
   [do something with $_.lastLogonTimestamp]    # --> this also always works

}
```

Comment: Yeah this is kinda expected and is how AD Module works, properties are lazily evaluated and if you try to do this in parallel the reference is lost. try `$users | Select-Object * | ForEach-Object -Parallel...` then it should work but I doubt how much multithreading will help you in that case

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for quick response - any document about this "laziness"? I'd thought once get-aduser finishes running, everything is populated and saved and ready for subsequent use. You comment sounds like there is a temporary area holds the returned data instead of pop them into $users that is intended to store the results

Comment: This is very specific to the Active Directory module interface and I'm not sure if you will find this documentated.

Comment: Did a quick test. As you predicted, [select *] triggered something made subsequent parallel block work. [EDIT] never mind my comment about [select samAccountName,...] - it also worked.

Comment: probably a copy-paste mistake, but you misspelled timestamp

Comment: yes, `Select-Object *` and `Select-Object prop1, prop2` both should force evaluation of the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter used by the Active Directory Module is not loaded automatically in the parallel runspaces which is why the property values are displayed as null by default. The solutions are either to force evaluation of all properties prior to passing the objects to the parallel runspaces:

```bash
$users | Select-Object * | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
```

Or forcing evaluation of a subset of the properties, the ones of interest:

```
$users | Select-Object prop1, prop2 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
```

Or to load the module in the parallel runspaces and by doing so the adapter should be accessible:

```bash
$users | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

This is most likely not documented as this behavior happens almost exclusively with the AD Module and its adapter, in addition the source code is closed but if you would like to read more about this you can start from [`PSPropertyAdapter` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pspropertyadapter?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) and as an example implementation, [`CimInstanceAdapter` source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/fc918bc1868f7bb5ca131e93f13b36223e16022b/src/System.Management.Automation/cimSupport/other/ciminstancetypeadapter.cs#L25).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! Accepted as answer. Overhead of select-object is going to offset the benefit of using parallel processing. Guessing import module in every single runspace is not much better, but testing it now.